# Cakephp 3.4 Where i found example for Paginator with language routing

Tags: cakephp, locale, url-routing, cakephp-3.x, paginator

I try to migrate from 2.x to 3.4, with an url based language routing.

Now the paginator links are like /books/index?page=2&lang=en

How can I transform to be like /en/books/index?page=2 or
how can I setup a new ruote if it is more simple.

In case that Dispatcher Filters is the best solution or Middleware can I have any example, because the documentation [of Dispatcher Filters](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/dispatch-filters.html#dispatcher-filters) and [Middleware](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html)is extremely poor.

Comment: rewrite your routes to your books controller and make langange param a prefix to all actions

Answer (score 0):

I think your routes need to be updated. If you have a number of routes that need language in them you can do something like:

```
// In config/routes.php
Router::scope('/', function($routes) {
  $routes->scope('/:lang', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/books', ['controller' => 'Books', 'action' => 'index']);
    $routes->connect('/books/:action/*', ['controller' => 'Books']);
  });
});
```

This will result in URLs like `/en/books` and `/en/books/view/1`

Comment: Thank you for this answer, now i found it also in the docs, but i understand how it works only because of You. Thanks.